# WPF Data Binding with Subclass

Tags: c#, wpf

I trying to get into WPF so for that I was trying to get a good example for myself to start with. After a few tries I started to get a bit confused about how the databinding in WFP works.

Here my example:

Lets say i got a 3 classes in my project:

- Product
- Category
- Tags

So for that I got these classes here:

**Category:**

```
public class Category
{
    private int id;
    private string name;

    public int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
}
```

**Tags:**

```
public class Tag
{
    private int id;
    private string name;

    public int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
}
```

**Product:**

```
public class Product
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private double price;
    private int categoryID;
    private ICollection<Tag> tags;

    public int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public double Price { get => price; set => price = value; }
    public int CategoryID { get => categoryID; set => categoryID = value; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get => tags; set => tags = value; }

    public Category Category
    {
        get => default(Category);
        set{}
    }
}
```

Lets say I got the data from somewhere to fill these classes:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

products.Add(new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "Toy Car", Price = 14.99, 
CategoryID = 2, Tags = new List<Tag>() { new Tag { Id = 1, Name = "Toy" }, 
new Tag { Id = 2, Name = "Kids" } } });

products.Add(new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "Water", Price = 14.99, 
CategoryID = 2, Tags = new List<Tag>() { new Tag { Id = 3, Name = "Food" } } 
});

List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
categories.Add(new Category() { Id = 1, Name = "Food" });
categories.Add(new Category() { Id = 2, Name = "Toys" });
```

My UI looks like this:

[image: UI]

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wfp_test"x:Class="wfp_test.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="productViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Product}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="productTagsViewSource" Source="{Binding Tags, Source={StaticResource productViewSource}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource productTagsViewSource}" >
    <Grid x:Name="grid1" DataContext="{StaticResource productViewSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Category:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="categoryComboBox" Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="Category" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120">
            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label Content="Id:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="idTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="Name:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="nameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="Price:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="priceTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Price, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="tagsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="382,155,10,64" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <ListView x:Name="productListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource productViewSource}}" Margin="10,10,10,296" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Control.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="categoryColumn" Header="Category" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Margin="6,-1,-6,-1">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Category}"/>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="categoryIDColumn" Header="Category ID" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding CategoryID, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="idColumn1" Header="Id" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="nameColumn1" Header="Name" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="priceColumn" Header="Price" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding Price, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "Toy Car", Price = 14.99, CategoryID = 2, Tags = new List<Tag>() { new Tag { Id = 1, Name = "Toy" }, new Tag { Id = 2, Name = "Kids" } } });
        products.Add(new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "Water", Price = 14.99, CategoryID = 1, Tags = new List<Tag>() { new Tag { Id = 3, Name = "Food" } } });

        List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
        categories.Add(new Category() { Id = 1, Name = "Food" });
        categories.Add(new Category() { Id = 2, Name = "Toys" });

        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource productViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("productViewSource")));
        categoryComboBox.ItemsSource = categories;
        productViewSource.Source = products;
    }
}
```

My first problem here the **categoryComboBox** is always empty. My second problem ist how do I set the **ValueMember** and **DisplayMember** of this box and where can I fill it with the Data from **categories**?

Answer (score 0):

The `DisplayMemberPath` should be set to "Name". You may also set `SelectedValuePath` to "Id":

```
<ComboBox x:Name="categoryComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" ... />
```

Comment: Now i got some items in the ComboBox but when i select a Product it dont select the right Category in the ComboBox

Comment: That's another issue, isn't it. Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask several questions in the same thread.

Comment: not for me becouse the control is not working like it should.

Comment: @Mace: Well, if you don't want to follow the guidelines for [how to ask questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it's entirely up to you. I wish you the best of luck trying to solve your issues.

Comment: Like i said the Problem is still not solved when i select a product the combobox is still empty ....  like you see in my screenshoot .... i rly thx you for you help so far but you not solving my problem here

Comment: Or to be more exactly there are items in my ComboBox but the Binding dont Apply to the Box. So thats why i ask two questions first one was how is it possible to select the right Category in my Combobox so its not empy "My first problem here the categoryComboBox is always empty" and the second was "how do I set the ValueMember and DisplayMember" so you solved the second thing but its only half of my Problem and thats all what i saying ...

Comment: @Mace: Are you saying that the categoryComboBox is empty, despite the fact that you set its ItemsSource in your event handler?